# How can i add extra fields in ELK Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

I am using ELK with kibana.

I am also using filebeat for sending data to Logstash.

The i have created look like this

```
{
    "mappings": {  
    "_default_": {
                   "properties": {
                                 "msg":{"type":"string", "index":"not_analyzed"}
                                 }
                 },
    "log": {
                   "properties": {
                                 "@timestamp":{"type":"date","format":"strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"},
                                 "@version":{"type":"string"},
                                 "beat": {
                                     "properties": {
                                           "hostname":{"type":"string"}, 
                                           "name":{"type":"string"},
                                                    }
                                          },
                                 "count":{"type":"long"},
                                 "host":{"type":"string"},
                                 "input_type":{"type":"string"},
                                 "message":{"type":"string"},
                                 "msg":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"},
                                 "offset":{"type":"long"},
                                 "source":{"type":"string"},
                                 "type":{"type":"string"}

                                 }
                 }
              }
}';
```

I want to know that just like beat has 2 fields like hostname and name. Is it possible to have add more fields like  `environment: dev` which i can see in kibana so that i can filter messages based on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can [specify additional fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuration-filebeat-options.html#configuration-fields) in your `filebeat.yml` configuration. Those new fields will be created. You have two options, you can either specify `fields` and/or `fields_under_root`.

If you use the former (see below), a new `fields` subgroup with your custom fields will appear in your document and you will be able to filter messages with `fields.environment: dev` in Kibana.

```
fields:
    environment: dev
```

If you use the latter (see below), your custom fields will appear at the top-level in your document and you will be able to filter messages with `environment: dev` in Kibana.

```
fields_under_root: true
```

Comment: do i need to do anything on elastic search side or logstash side or kibana side or only in filebeat.yml

Comment: Only in filebeat.yml. There should not be nothing more to do.

Comment: The `fields_under_root` is a boolean, so the way the second example should be written is: `fields:
  environment: dev
fields_under_root: true
`